# cannot Imports System.Web.Script.Serializer

Tags: .net, vb.net

when I try to append this line to the code:

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serializer
```

it showing me error like this:

> Namespace or type specified in the Imports
>   'System.Web.Script.Serializer' doesn't contain any public member or
>   cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and
>   contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element
>   name doesn't use any aliases.

then I searching references in google, say that should `Add References` then choose System.Net.Extension.dll in .NET tab, but it not found in the list

[image]

I try to import the System.Net.Extension.dll with manually. I open `Add Reference` dialog, in `Browse` tab, I select `System.Web.Extension.dll` in `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0`, then klik Ok. but it still doesn't work instead show me error message agains like this:

[image]

[image]

whats wrong with my VS2010 ??

Answer (score 1):

That assembly requires the .NET 4.0 (full profile).  Your project is currently targeting .NET 4.0 client profile.  This is the typical default for most projects in 2010.  Change the target framework to just the plain old vanilla .NET 4.0 and it should work.

For a VB.net project, you can do this by opening the project properties and going to the `Compile` tab then the `Advanced Compile Settings`.  From there, change the `Target framework (all configurations)` to `.NET Framework 4`.

[image]